# How to use local beamer theme in project source folder

Tags: beamer, miktex, themes

Is it possible to use a local theme placed in the the same folder as your current `beamer` project? I.e. having a them in `/project-name/theme/` that you can make updates to and get the changes instantly when compiling your project.

This would be really handy when developing new themes as you (at least in Windows using MikTeX) have to constantly refresh the name database when developing.

Comment: Yes. MikTeX will find all themes or packages you have in your working folder.

Comment: Hi Ignasi, thank for answering my question, however this is not true in the setup I have on my machines. Do you need to add anything to the theme declaration? E.g. \usetheme{theme\my-theme}.

Comment: Ignasi is right. It's a big difference to have the package files in the working directory or in a subfolder of the working directory.

Comment: Hi Marco, Thank you for replying to my question. I did not fully understand your answer, but did you mean that if I put the Theme files directly into the working directory (wd) instead of having them in wd/theme this should work? This is a quick fix, but I would really like to be able to have all the theme files in a subfolder. Do You have any input on how to achieve this?

Comment: I don't have access to my computer now, but in the meanwhile, could try with `\usepackage{theme\beamerthememy-theme}` instead of  `usetheme`?

Comment: Hi Ignasi, this seems to work in general, but not in my specific case as I have a main theme file calling a subtheme file.
themefile.sty: \usetheme{subtheme}. I could change this to \usepackage as well, and also change all directories for the graphics used. But would this behave when I complete the theme and want to move it to miktex/tex/latex/?

Comment: Somebody else will explain it better, but I think that `LaTeX` can find everytwhere inside `tex` tree but outside there it's only capable of looking at your working folder. In fact if you want to include figures not placed in your working directory  you have to declare an special `graphicspath`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at `beamerbasetheme.sty` file will see that `\usetheme` commands are defined as particular `\usepackage` commands. So `\usetheme{my-theme-name}` is converted to `\usepackage{beamerthememy-theme-name}`. Similar conversions are done with `color`, `outer`, ... themes.

```
\mode
<presentation>
{
  \def\beamer@calltheme#1#2#3{%
    \def\beamer@themelist{#2}
    \@for\beamer@themename:=\beamer@themelist\do
    {\usepackage[{#1}]{#3\beamer@themename}}}

  \newcommand\usetheme[2][]{\beamer@calltheme{#1}{#2}{beamertheme}}
  \newcommand\usecolortheme[2][]{\beamer@calltheme{#1}{#2}{beamercolortheme}}
  \newcommand\usefonttheme[2][]{\beamer@calltheme{#1}{#2}{beamerfonttheme}}
  \newcommand\useoutertheme[2][]{\beamer@calltheme{#1}{#2}{beameroutertheme}}
  \newcommand\useinnertheme[2][]{\beamer@calltheme{#1}{#2}{beamerinnertheme}}
}
```

So if you want to place all your theme files inside a folder inside your working folder, the best solution I can provide is using `\usepackage{theme-folder/my manually translated theme name}`.

There is a better solution which I cannot provide which consist in hacking previous command with a fourth parameter consisting in your theme folder. Use these new commands while working whith your theme and forget them when you finish it and move all theme files to a `regular` tex folder.

Comment: What about options passed to beamer? How to handle those.

Comment: @Kyslik What does it mean? Could you show me an example?

Comment: \usepackage[options for beamer style]{folder/theme} like that

Comment: @Kyslik I don't know. Did you try it? Did you found any problem? If you found it, I think the best solution would be to ask a new question, because you will get a larger and better audience. You can mention this question if you consider it convenient.

Comment: @Kyslik AFAIK there are no options to be added to an  `\usetheme`...