# Called \usecolortheme from folder

Tags: beamer, templates

I just created a cholor them for beamer wrapped in a file `bearmercolorthememyct.sty`.
I put this file in a folder name *template*.
Now, in the main i called `\usecolortheme{template\myct}`... but it fails!
is there a way to called the *template* folder where the `bearmercolorthememyct.sty` is located?
thanks

Comment: Which operating system do you use? try perhaps `\usecolortheme{./template/myct}`

Comment: I use windows. No it doesn't work. When I include the `.sty` in the same file that the main `.tex` it works.

Comment: I can't test on windows, but maybe the complete path i.e. C:\...\template\myct might work?

Comment: thank you samcarter. I found the answer from [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123700/how-to-use-local-beamer-theme-in-project-source-folder). As I'm calling a subfolder of my working directory, I have to use `\usepackage{template/beamercolorthememyct}` rather than `\usecolortheme{myct}` which work only if the file is in the working directory.

Comment: Can you turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

So, here is the answer mostly coming from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123700/how-to-use-local-beamer-theme-in-project-source-folder).

The code `\usecolortheme{myct}` loads the file `usecolorthememyct.sty`. If this file is included in another folder than the working directory, we have to use `\usepackage{template/beamercolothememyct}`.