# Created own theme

Tags: beamer

I'm using this created theme called myown.sty in my presentation:

```
\useoutertheme[footline=authortitle]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\usecolortheme{orchid}


\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{rgb}{0.137,0.466,0.741}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=beamer@blendedblue}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black} \setbeamercolor{item}{fg=black}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=1.7ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=1.7ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
} \mode <all>

\makeatletter
\DeclareOptionBeamer{compress}{\beamer@compresstrue}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\mode<presentation>

% The footline template is a modification of the one used in the
% Torino theme, Copyright 2007 by Marco Barisione
\setbeamercolor*{lineup}{parent=palette primary}
\setbeamercolor*{linemid}{parent=palette secondary}
\setbeamercolor*{linebottom}{parent=palette tertiary}
\setbeamercolor*{page header}{parent=titlelike}
\mode <all>

% some lengths (the height of the lines)
\newlength{\beamer@decolines@linemid}
\setlength{\beamer@decolines@linemid}{.015\paperheight}

\newlength{\beamer@decolines@lineup}
\setlength{\beamer@decolines@lineup}{.025\paperheight}

\newlength{\beamer@decolines@linebottom}
\setlength{\beamer@decolines@linebottom}{.01\paperheight}


% String used between the current page and the total page count.
\def\beamer@decolines@pageofpages{/}

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{decolines theme}
{
  \leavevmode%
  % First line.
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.8\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@lineup,dp=0pt]{lineup}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@lineup,dp=0pt,right]{}%
    \hbox{\usebeamerfont{palette primary}\footnotesize\insertframenumber{} \beamer@decolines@pageofpages{} \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  } %
  % Second line.
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@linemid,dp=0pt]{linemid}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  } %
  % Third line.
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.9\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@linebottom,dp=0pt]{linebottom}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@linebottom,dp=0pt]{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

I have this myown.sty theme in the same directory as the presentation but it does not work and I get reply "beamerthememyown.sty" not found. What is wrong?

My preambule is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{BeamerColor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{myown}
\usecolortheme[named=salmon]{structure}
\setbeamercovered{transparent} }

\setbeamercolor{lower separation line head}{bg=LightSteelBlue3}
\setbeamercolor{lineup}{bg=salmon}
\setbeamercolor{linemid}{bg=IndianRed2}
\setbeamercolor{linebottom}{bg=LightSteelBlue3}
```

Comment: So, what is the question? BTW, edit your code to be compilable.

Comment: The error message tells it all! `beamer` prefixes whatever is passed to `\usetheme` with `beamertheme`. Just save your theme as `beamerthememyown.sty` and `\usetheme{myown}` will find it.

Comment: @Daniel that should be an answer! :)

Comment: Not a duplicate but related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123770/1952

Answer (score 2):

> I have this `myown.sty` theme in the same directory as the presentation but it does not work and I get reply `beamerthememyown.sty` not found. What is wrong?

Sometimes, error messages are *actually* useful :-)

The file name of your theme style file needs the `beamertheme` prefix, the format is `beamertheme<name>.sty`, which can then be loaded with `\usetheme{<name>}`.

This is also covered by the Beamer user guide (§15.1):

> `\usetheme[⟨options⟩]{⟨name list⟩}`
>
> Installs the presentation theme named `⟨name⟩`. Currently, the effect of this command is the same as saying `\usepackage` for the style file named `beamertheme⟨name⟩.sty` for each `⟨name⟩` in the `⟨name list⟩`.